# Offline Phonegap Build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-3, cordova-2.0.0, phonegap-desktop-app

By means of an Adobe Phonegap account (https://build.phonegap.com/apps) I could create mobile apps using my web application for all types of mobile platforms like IOS, Android, Windows. But, for this to happen, I have to upload my project zip to cloud.

Is it possible to create the apps (for all mobile platforms) **offline**, in my pc itself, without uploading my project zip to cloud? Is there any desktop application that does a similar job as build.phonegap.com?

Comment: Check it out http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap-build-a-feed-reader-project-structure--mobile-20265

Comment: Yes....you can use eclipse with corodova in your system

Comment: @anptk, can I create IOS app in my windows PC by using eclipse and cordova??

Comment: I am not a master in this, But i think Coding is possible in windows+eclipse, And building(packaging) will  be a problem. For that you have to find some online platforms NB:-i am not sure online platforms are free or not.

Comment: If you want a copy of phonegap build on your computer where you just put your files and all the platform apps are created, that is not possible. You can do local development with phonegap and cordova, but you have to install each SDK and configure the computer, you need a mac for iOS and windows 8 for WP8

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can build your app locally and offline.

BUT you should keep in mind that you have to use IDEs for that.

For android you can use Eclipse or Android studio on MacOs or Windows.

For ios you have to use xCode and MacOs.

---

Pros and cons of locally environment:

pros:

- you have access for native code and can change plugins and etc.
- realtime debugging from device and simulator

cons:

- it will take time to understand what to do
- for building app for ios you need MacOs (virtual machine is OK)

---

You can read about different platforms: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_index.md.html#Platform%20Guides

Answer (score 1):

If the question is "Can I build locally a phonegap/cordova app for IOS, android or windows phone on a Windows PC", the answer is unfortunatly no.

To build a app for a platform you need to install the sdk for that platform.

What that means is that :

- for android you can build on a mac, a linux or a PC
- for windows phone you can build only on a windows 8 pc (or on a mac running windows 8)
- for ios you can only build on a mac (as the ios sdk can only be installed on macs).

By the way, even if you are using phonegap build, you can't publish ios apps if you don't have a mac.

Comment: Untrue. There are online services which allow you to publish for iOS without a Mac.

Comment: If you are refering to services like MacinCloud, the thing is that you rent a Mac online but eventually you end up using a mac (even if you don't have to physically own it). My point that you can't  publish an app using only PG build. But maybe instead of just down-voting could you elaborate and indicate which service you are thinking about, this could be usefull for those looking for that kind of service.

Comment: And "by the way" the question was about generating a local build for platforms like ios on a Windows computer, and your "Untrue" statement is just about an off-topic adition I made to be more informative.

Comment: @QuickFix: +1 for your solution since it does not deserve a downvote. But could not accept it as the main answer since it's not providing a solution for my problem.

Comment: @Quick_Silver as it is just not possible to build for ios on a windows pc, good luck for finding a solution ;) The only solution I could see would be renting a mac on MacinCloud. As 95% of the code should be common between all the platforms, you should need it mostly for generating the builds and submitting the app, so the 1$/hour plan should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

you can definitely build app offline. I've worked on phonegap for android and I've successfully build and generated .apk file got for android.

you should have ANT environvement setup in-order to build.

for example:

> "cordova build android"

try to execute this line inside the folder of your application path in the command prompt and check what are the requirements that your system need in-order to build the required app